# why tensorflow train.Saver() saves initial variable values and not the modified values ?

Tags: tensorflow

I have following code to initialize variable v3 and v4. After initializing variable v3 and v4, I am modifying these variables and saving it in a checkpoint file:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
v3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([4,2]), name="v3")
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)
with sess.as_default():
    print(v3.eval())
    v3 = tf.transpose(v3)
    print(v3.eval())
    sess.run(v3)
    v4 = tf.Variable(v3+3, name="v4")
    v4 = v4 + 5
    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init_op)
    print(v4.eval())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, "pktest_ckpt")
```

This print the following values of v3, transposed v3, and v4 values:

```
[[ 0.90765333  0.61777163]
 [ 0.5102632   0.45610023]
 [ 0.36511779  0.5465256 ]
 [ 0.61696458  0.86357415]]
[[ 0.90765333  0.5102632   0.36511779  0.61696458]
 [ 0.61777163  0.45610023  0.5465256   0.86357415]]
[[ 8.96951866  8.24961662  8.30669975  8.54586029]
 [ 8.55886841  8.16989517  8.48039341  8.06889534]]
```

After a restore variables from the checkpoint file, I see the variables values are the initial initialized ones and not the modified values:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
mg = tf.train.import_meta_graph("pktest_ckpt.meta")
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for v in tf.global_variables():
        print(v)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("./"))  
    print(sess.run('v4:0'))
```

It prints:

```
<tf.Variable 'v3:0' shape=(4, 2) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'v4:0' shape=(2, 4) dtype=float32_ref>
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./pktest_ckpt
[[ 3.75337863  3.52812386  3.97137022  3.76210618]
 [ 3.81927872  3.41938591  3.82610369  3.20377684]]
```

My expectation was to get v3 of shape (2,4) and v4 values as
    [[ 8.96951866  8.24961662  8.30669975  8.54586029]
     [ 8.55886841  8.16989517  8.48039341  8.06889534]]

Can anyone explain why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I got the answer. I should save the variables this way:

```
import tensorflow as tf
sess = tf.Session()
v3 = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([4,2]), name="v3")
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)
with sess.as_default():
    v4 = tf.Variable(v3+3, name="v4")
    init_op = tf.variables_initializer([v3,v4])
    sess.run(init_op)
    do_add = v4.assign(tf.add(v4,5))
    sess.run(do_add)

    print(v4.eval())
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.save(sess, "pktest_ckpt")
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because you're not actually running the operations after your second init. Try adding `session.run([v3, v4])` after your second `session.run(init_op)`

Comment: tried running. New values doesn't go to saved model. I think we have to use assign operator as I posted in my answer. However, it's very counter intuitive to write extra line of codes to create operation step and run it in session. Tensorflow should be doing this automatically.